# How do I change location of pivot point in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to **move pivot point** to the center of an object so it rotates around its center. How can I do this?

[image]

I see no option in Xcode editor for doing this. I tried changing the pivot point programmatically:

```
    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Heart.scn")!

    // change pivot point
    scene.rootNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

But it doesn't work either, the object still rotates around its old pivot point.

Comment: You changed rootNode's pivot, is it the heart's pivot?

Comment: No idea, how can I verify that?

Comment: It depends on the scene content. Name the heart root name in xcode, and use childNodeWithName to find it and change its pivot.

Comment: A way to get the base node of your heart: open your .scn in the editor and display the scene view graph by clicking on the icon, lower left in the editor window. Its root node will be at the top of the graph (tree) in the resulting display. You can rename it there if desired. Also check out what Hal is saying, what is your code actually set up to rotate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The heart is (probably) not the root node of your scene. It is a child of the root node (as are the default camera and any lights). So you could try

```
// (use the Scene Editor to figure out what the node name really is)
if let heart = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("HEART", recursively: true) {
    heart.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
}
```

As for the Scene Editor...are you sure you're manipulating the heart, and not the entire scene? I've also seen some SO and Devforum traffic that suggests (but doesn't prove) that some parameters set in the Scene Editor aren't honored at runtime.

Comment: what's the "recursively: true" part all about?

Comment: @SKOOP - "recursively" means to look for the node named "HEART" (and of course you need to match the name you used in the Node Inspector (if you open the scene graph in the node editor you'll also see the name there) regardless of how deep it is in the hierarchy, rather than just as a "first level" node below the root. In this case, "recursively: false" will likely work as well, but that will be apparent if you look at the scene graph in the node editor.

Comment: Suppose I have model  Which has some pivot applied + Transformation matrix applied 

Now I need to pivot to identify and want model to be at same position ( change pivot change model position as well)  

is there any way to convert this ?